# Shopify Dawn Theme li alignment not showing correctly

Tags: shopify

when I create the blog post the li dots show up correctly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnWwN.jpg)

but when I posted on the site, it looks off for some reason, can someone help me fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSyKs.jpg)

URL: https://convomediagroup.com/blogs/convo-money/us-stock-market-weekly-outlook-june-11-2023

I am not a coder, so please take it slow step by step with me thank you : )

I don't even know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

found the answer by adding the following CSS code to base.css

> .rte ul, .rte ol {    list-style-position: outside; }